# What's wrong here? (void type pointer)

Tags: c, pointers, void

I know there is a problem but I can't understand why. I'm a beginner. Thanks for the help !

```
int main()
{￼
    int a = 5;
    int* p = &a;
    void* p2 = p;
    printf("%d", (int)(*p2) );

    return 0;
}
```

I also have a problem with this:

```
int main ()
{
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int *p = a;
if(++p == ++a)

     printf("equal");
else
     printf("not equal");
}
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Although these examples contain problems easy to spot, please post your exact compiler error messages any time you ask about something that doesn't compile.  They contain useful hints.

Comment: Remember what `*` does.  `*` turns a *pointer* into *storage*. Storage has a type associated with it, but a void pointer has no type associated with it. So using `*` on a void pointer gives you a storage location that stores ... what?  We can't say! So you are saying "turn this thing that I don't know what it is into an int", but *we don't know what it is*, so *we don't know how to turn it into an int*.

Comment: In the future try to ask only one question per question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having with the first code sample is that you're trying to get the value (operator *) before casing back to int* - try to cast first.

The 2nd code is comparing two pointers and not values - and 
++a is similar to moving the beginning of an array - which is a constant.

Answer (score 3):

In the first code, `(int)(*p2)` is wrong because you can't defer a `void` pointer. You first need cast it to `int*` and only then defer it: `*(int*)p2`

In the second code, you can't do `++a` because `a` is a constant(the pointer to the array is constant, not the data in the array) so you can't change it's value.

Comment: Rather, you can't do `++a` because `a` is an array, and whenever you use the name of an array in an expression, it "decays" into a pointer to the first object. But since this temporarily existing pointer-to-first object is no lvalue, you cannot use ++ on it. (You can regard it as if it was `int* const` type, though strictly speaking I don't think it is.)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the first problem , you have used a generic pointer,as a beginner there are some things that you need to keep in mind while using generic pointers :

`*We cannot de-reference generic pointer.`

`*We can find the size of generic pointer using sizeof operator.`

`*Generic pointer can hold any type of pointers like char pointer, struct pointer,array of pointer etc with a valid typecasting.`

Problem 1 i have rephrased as :

```
int main()
{
 int a = 5;
 void* p = &a;
 int *p2= (int *)p;
 printf("%d", *p2 );
 return 0;
```

}

and Problem 2 :

```
int main ()
{
 int a[3] = {1,2,3};
 int *p = a;
 if(++p == &a[1])
      printf("equal");
 else
      printf("not equal");
}
```

Furthermore, please refer [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays)